# How to include an additional element in ng-repeat at a specific index location?

Tags: angularjs

```
<!-- if (index == 2) <div>{{data.customText}}</div> -->
<div ng-repeat-start="product in products">{{product.headline}}</div>
<div ng-repeat-end>{{product.text}}</div>
```

Let's assume I'm showing 5 products, and I want to display additional content `{{product.customText}}` on 3rd position in between. How could I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `$index` attribute and `ng-show` for showing conditional element. For example the following will be shown only for the 3rd element

```js
var myApp = angular.module("myApp", []);

myApp.controller("MyCtrl", ["$scope",
  function($scope) {
    $scope.products = [{
      headline: "headline1",
      text: "text 1"
    }, {
      headline: "headline2",
      text: "text 2"
    }, {
      headline: "headline3",
      text: "text 3"
    }, {
      headline: "headline4",
      text: "text 4"
    }, {
      headline: "headline5",
      text: "text 5"
    }];
    $scope.data = {
      customText: "customText"
    };
  }
]);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<html>

<body ng-app="myApp">
  <div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
    <span ng-repeat="product in products">
    <div ng-show="$index == 2">{{data.customText}}</div>
    <div>{{product.headline}}</div>
    <div>{{product.text}}</div>
      </span>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Would it be also possible to move the `product.headline` below the  `index=2` inserted element in this case? So that the `customText` comes before a repeated block of headline+text?

Comment: Also, what if the text to be show is not contained inside the `product` variable, but in a different one, like `data.customText`. In this case I don't see any output for  `ng-show`.

Comment: I just added an example how you can do what you asked for. As the angular version was not recent I couldn't use ng-repeat-start and etc. Basically you can show anything you want conditionally.

Comment: Ty so much for you complete example!

Comment: One more question: what if `product.customText` is also an array that must be repeated. See example http://jsfiddle.net/5DMjt/2230/, it does not work that way.

Comment: In your example $index is overwritten by the inner ng-repeat. You can check out the following example to see the difference. http://jsfiddle.net/5DMjt/2233/

Comment: Great, I understand. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

You can use $index to do so.

```
<div ng-repeat-start="product in products">{{product.headline}}</div>
<div ng-if="$index == 2">{{product.customText}}</div>
<div ng-repeat-end>{{product.text}}</div>
```